# Object.create method in javascript

Tags: javascript, mozilla, object-create

Being a beginner in javascript, i tried to understand Object.create() method from here

https://developer-new.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create

In the example code, line 18. A accessor property is created with writable set to true. I also read that writable is only for data descriptors.

Tried running,

```
var o = Object.create(Object.prototype, {
  // foo is a regular "value property"
  foo: { 
    writable:true, configurable:true, value: "hello" 
  },
  // bar is a getter-and-setter (accessor) property
  bar: {
    writable: true,
    configurable: false,
    get: function() { return 10 },
    set: function(value) { console.log("Setting `o.bar` to", value) }
  }
  });
console.log(o);
```

I get `invalid property error`.

Comment: is the mozilla reference incorrect?

Comment: The Mozilla reference was indeed incorrect.  It's a wiki, so I just logged in and fixed it. (They're rolling out a new wiki very shortly, so you might not see the fix just yet, depending on whether you are enrolled in the beta, I think.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The issue is that `writable` and `set`/`get` are mutually exclusive.  The code generates this helpful error in Chrome:

```
Invalid property. A property cannot both have accessors and be writable...
```

This makes some logical sense: if you have `set`/`get` accessors on a property, that property is never going to be written to and/or read from, because any attempts to read/write it will be intercepted by the accessor functions.  If you define a property as `writable` *and* give it accessor functions, you are simultaneously saying:

1. "The value of this property can be directly altered," and
2. "Block all attempts to read and/or write to this property; instead, use these functions."

The error is simply stopping you from specifying a contradiction.  I assume from the fact that you wrote a getter and setter, you don't really want the property to be `writable`.  Just remove that line, and your code runs perfectly.

Comment: +1. Just delete the `writable: true` bit from `bar`, and it's fine.

Comment: @John You might be interested in John Resigs blog post about ECMAScript 5: http://ejohn.org/blog/ecmascript-5-objects-and-properties/

Answer (score 10):

Late answer, not looking for votes, but hoping this will be helpful.

There are two kinds of properties.  Each property is EITHER:

1. a **data property** which has these four attributes:

   - value
   - writable
   - enumerable
   - configurable
2. OR an **accessor property** which has these four attributes:

   - get
   - set
   - enumerable
   - configurable

Therefore there is no property that can have both `get` and `writable`.  That's just the way JavaScript is!  Please see section 8.6 of the [ECMAScript Standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/Ecma-262.pdf) for the gory details.

Comment: This answer was very helpful for me.  I was getting the same error, even though I had writable set to false.  Now I understand, because I had defined a 'get', the property was an 'accessor property' and therefore it's illegal to set any value for 'writable' (even if you set it to false)