# Object property cannot be set via setter while using Object.create

Tags: javascript, object, setter

On my attempt to learn more about Object.create I came across [Object.create(): the New Way to Create Objects in JavaScript](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/object.create-the-new-way-to-create-objects-in-javascript.html).

An example from the above page:

```
var Car2 = Object.create(null); //this is an empty object, like {}
Car2.prototype = {
  getInfo: function() {
    return 'A ' + this.color + ' ' + this.desc + '.';
  }
};

var car2 = Object.create(Car2.prototype, {
  //value properties
  color:   { writable: true,  configurable:true, value: 'red' },
  //concrete desc value
  rawDesc: { writable: false, configurable:true, value: 'Porsche boxter' },
  // data properties (assigned using getters and setters)
  desc: { 
    configurable:true, 
    get: function ()      { return this.rawDesc.toUpperCase();  },
    set: function (value) { this.rawDesc = value.toLowerCase(); }  
  }
}); 
car2.color = 'blue';
alert(car2.getInfo()); //displays 'A blue PORSCHE BOXTER.'
```

Question:

1. How correct is the above example? <s>[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11682074/1640617) seems to contradict the example above.</s>It seems to give the notion that `rawDesc` could be a private member that could be modified only via getter/setter of `desc`. Is this useful in any way?
2. Also, trying to set value for `desc` using `car2.desc = 'Merc'` doesn't seem to work. Why is that so?
3. What parts of Object.defineProperty and Object.create are similar?

Research:

Somewhat related question: [Why can I set [enumerability and] writability of unconfigurable property descriptors?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9829817/1640617)
I have tried removing `writable: false` and `value: 'Porsche boxter'` and tried setting the value but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Some comments:

```
var Car2 = Object.create(null); //this is an empty object, like {}
```

The comment isn't quite correct. The internal prototype of `Car2` (i.e. its `[[Prototype]]`) will be `null`, so it doesn't inherit any properties of `Object.prototype`, whereas an object created using `{}` does.

```
Car2.prototype = {
  ...
};

var car2 = Object.create(Car2.prototype, {
```

It seems pointless to create `Car2` since it isn't a function and can't be used as a constructor nor has it inherited any of the standard Object methods. It's just a placeholder for the object assigned to `Car2.prototype`. But I guess this is just an example.

And for the questions…

> How correct is the above example? This answer seems to contradict the example above.

How does it contradict the example?

> Also, trying to set value for desc using car2.desc = 'Merc' doesn't seem to work. Why is that so?

Because the setter for `desc` actually changes `rawDesc`, but `rawDesc` is set to `writeable: false`. Change it to `writeable: true` and the value is changed. But it's a public property anyway so a bit pointless to have its value set by setting some other property.

> What parts of Object.defineProperty and Object.create are similar?

[Object.create](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.5) and [Object.defineProperty](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.2.3.6) are adjacent in ECMA–262, not hard to work it out. Basically, the first just adds a property to an existing object, the second creates a new object and sets its `[[Prototype]]` (i.e. it's equivalent to a constructor).

Comment: Thanks and it's indeed an copy-pasted example, as mentioned in the question. As for the example contradicting the answer, I guess I misconstrued `rawDesc` and desc being the same property. Just that on first glance, the example looks to be providing a way to have private members ie., `rawDesc` in this case, which can be accessed only via `desc`. Btw @RobG any chance your are the same person (Rob Gravelle) who wrote the article with this same example [here](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/object.create-the-new-way-to-create-objects-in-javascript.html) ?